# Dynamically increase Relative layout's height

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-relativelayout

i have a list adapter for my list. the list item is created by inflating a layout which has a relative layout with 50dp height. i want to change the height of the relative layout to be wrap content on orientation landscape and in portrait it be 50 dp. how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create one folder in the `res` folder called `layout-land` for landscape mode. Inside that folder rewrite your xml file with height as wrap-content. In the xml of  layout folder keep the height as 50 dp.

Example: let say you have relative layout in `abc.xml` inside `res\layout` as given:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="50">"
     <!--Other code -->
</RelativeLayout >
```

Create `abc.xml` inside `res\layou-land` as given below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">"
         <!--Other code -->
 </RelativeLayout >
```

If you are in landscape or portrait Android looks for the layout file in either the -port or -land directory first, if it's not found then it falls back to the default layout directory.

You can read about providing alternative resources [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html). There are many more options than just land and port.

Answer (score 1):

Define another layout with the same name in `/layout-land` and change `layout_height` to wrap content.

Answer (score 1):

you can create two different layouts file, put the portrait layout in res/layout/ folder and the landscape layout on res/layout-land folder.